# Detect if an object in 3D space is within/touches a UI image's bounds

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a square aim set to the middle of the screen, this is an UI image. **Now I want to detect if enemies (visualized by pink boxes here) are within this aimbox but also, and this is very important, if only a part of the enemy is within the aimbox.**

- What I found so far is that I can't use (please correct me if I'm
  wrong):
- Raycast from midscreen, because then you have to aim directly at the
  enemy.
- Boxcast because it only creates the box at the target raycast point.
- Raycast from the enemy to screen to detect object on screenpoint,
  because the ray is cast from mid of the enemy.
- Spherecast, because it's not a box and thus unreliable.
- Using a box object (with collider) with a huge length into the
  screen, because visually it will not retain the size of the aimbox
  image.

I have tought about using several raycasts from the screen into the world using start points at 3,6,9,12 o'clock of the aimbox image position as well as from the cornors and midpoint of the UI aimbox image. But this seem like a really unreliable solution.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

I need to detect all the boxes that are within, and are partial within, the aimbox UI image.

Comment: SphereCast isn't unreliable because it's a sphere, not a box ([BoxCast exists](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html), but because you're trying to cast against a perspective volume defined by a 2D cross-section. The best thing I can come up with is a [Frustum Test](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/), however, correctly calculating the frustum planes is going to be difficult.

Comment: @Draco18s Oh no I didn't mean SphereCast is unreliable in general, but in my case the shape of a sphere would make the aim unreliable.
Anyway. After a short read up on Frustum I might be able to use that.
I guess drawing a box from the near to the far clipping plane and then get all colliders within this box.
Biggest problem I guess is calculating the 4 corners of the aimbox and then utilize them.

Comment: That's why I said BoxCast exists (it'd be the right shape). ;) But yes, the Fustum test should work, its a problem of calculation. I did do the math once, but it was based on a hypothetical camera component being attached to an arbitrary game object, so there were assumptions made (e.g. field of view) rather than using known points. It's still doable, though.

Comment: Right. But as far as I could tell from testing the boxcasting it will create a box at the point hit of the raycast and therefore if the aimbox has the enemy only partially within, the ray point will still miss the enemy and the box from the boxcast will be way behind the enemy and therefore not hit it at all.
Or am I using it all wrong?

Comment: That is incorrect. BoxCast (and SphereCast and the other similar methods) are a *volumetric raycast.* That is, the "ray" has thickness and will collide with things that only partially enter the volume. CapsuleCast is specifically designed for checking to see if a player (or other moving entity) can move in the direction of the Cast (i.e. will not collide with walls, ceilings, floors, other entities, etc). The different shapes are the shape being Cast out (box, sphere, capsule).