# Get point in 3D space aligned to camera view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, frustum

I am trying to use Frustum to detect whether or not an object is within a square part of the screen (see image below) It's a UI image working as the aimbox not a 3D object.

The original post is here: [Detect if an object in 3D space is within/touches a UI image's bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349536/detect-if-an-object-in-3d-space-is-within-touches-a-ui-images-bounds)

Right now I can get the Frustum and drawing the box to work, but only looking in one direction.

I need to be able to calculate new points when the camera turns and I can't figure out how.

The code below kinda works, but I need to offset the positions so they align with the view when the camera is moving.

**Edit:** Right now nothing is supposed to happen but drawing the box and get that to work. Collision detection comes after.

```
// Draw aimbox
Vector3 camPosOffset = camPos + cam.transform.forward * maxDistance;

float frustumHeight = (2.0f * maxDistance * Mathf.Tan(cam.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad));

cubeVerts[0] = new Vector3(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
cubeVerts[1] = new Vector3(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
cubeVerts[2] = new Vector3(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
cubeVerts[3] = new Vector3(camPos.x, camPos.y, camPos.z);
cubeVerts[4] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[5] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[6] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[7] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);

for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i += 2)
{
    Debug.DrawLine(cubeVerts[edges[i]], cubeVerts[edges[i + 1]], Color.red);
}
```

https://imgur.com/iXQlE04

Comment: Why not make the box collider (the Aimbox) longer, and just detect if the object is within the box fully?

Comment: @Hristo Because going that route the end of the box will get smaller and smaller the further the target is, well visually anyway. So the aimbox will be off because of perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest version: Make the aimbox a child of the camera.

Alternative Solution, use camPosOffset also for the first 4 verts like this:

```
cubeVerts[0] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[1] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[2] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[3] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z);
cubeVerts[4] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z) + cam.forward * 3;
cubeVerts[5] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z) + cam.forward * 3;
cubeVerts[6] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z) + cam.forward * 3;
cubeVerts[7] = new Vector3(camPosOffset.x + frustumHeight, camPosOffset.y - frustumHeight, camPosOffset.z) + cam.forward * 3;
```

Comment: Because of other functionalities of the aimbox I cannot have it as a child sadly. And also, it's an image and from I can tell I can't use that to determine if if hovers over, or partially over, a 3D object.

I found a solution though, which I have just posted. From your code alone I can't tell if yours does the same thing. Thanks for answering though :)

Comment: Well your solution uses `cam.transform.forward` in the first 4 verts, which was (part of) my point. You previously had them at the cam Position, so it was not affected by the rotation. (Basically your Question)

So I hope my example helped you. Glad you solved it

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling for almost two days I got exactly what I wanted.

```
        //Draw aimbox

    float frustumHeight = ((2.0f * maxDistance * Mathf.Tan(cam.fieldOfView/20 * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad))); //cam.fieldOfView/20, I divide by 20 because I only need a small square of the view

    cubeVerts[0] = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * 25; //25 is the distance from the camera to the object it follows
    cubeVerts[1] = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * 25;
    cubeVerts[2] = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * 25;
    cubeVerts[3] = cam.transform.position + cam.transform.forward * 25;
    cubeVerts[4] = cam.transform.position + (cam.transform.right * -frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.up * frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.forward * maxDistance);
    cubeVerts[5] = cam.transform.position + (cam.transform.right * frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.up * frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.forward * maxDistance);
    cubeVerts[6] = cam.transform.position + (cam.transform.right * -frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.up * -frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.forward * maxDistance);
    cubeVerts[7] = cam.transform.position + (cam.transform.right * +frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.up * -frustumHeight) + (cam.transform.forward * maxDistance);

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.Length; i += 2)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(cubeVerts[edges[i]], cubeVerts[edges[i + 1]], Color.red);
    }
```

Here the altered frustum view follows the camera at any given time.